# inc increment the same value from all rows of a table phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my database called `time` and keeps message time of a forum I have. The format of the time on them is in timestamp format.
So a date of `14/05/2018 14:14` has timestamp `1526307254`.

Because I imported data it with a migration tool. All imported messages are wrong and all messages have `+` this value `-25927214` on their date (`300 days, 2 hours, 0 minutes and 14 seconds`) so I want just to increment 
from table column named `time` for all of his rows the `25927214` value.

The `time` is part of the izlt_kunena_messages. Can someone help for the right query syntax to execute at phpMyAdmin to fix the dates?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `UPDATE izlt_kunena_messages SET time = time + 25927214;` ?

Comment: - 25927214 did the job! thanks very much. Everyday learning something new!